# Spark writes parquet with partitionBy throws FileAlreadyExistsException in its own temporary working space

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

It seems to be a simple task :(

What I am trying to do is to read from a csv file and turn it into a hive partitioned parquet dataset.

```py
master = "local[*]"
app_name = "convert_to_parquet"
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName(app_name)
    .master(master)
    .getOrCreate()
)

csv_path = "<csv-path>"
in_df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv(csv_path)
out_df = in_df.selectExpr("trim(OBJECTID) AS ID",
                          "trim(NAME) AS NAME",
                          "trim(CITY) AS CITY",
                          "trim(STATE) AS STATE", "X", "Y")
out_path = "<out-dir>"
# make sure output directory doesn't exist before writing
shutil.rmtree(out_path, ignore_errors=True)

out_df.write.partitionBy(["CITY"]).parquet(out_path)
```

I got error:

```
23/02/24 01:54:22 ERROR Utils: Aborting task                        (0 + 1) / 1]
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: File already exists: file: <out-dir>/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202302240154215533456461598462887_0002_m_000000_2/CITY=Apex/part-00000-0de20945-1012-4a7a-b183-c4235717a0a2.c000.snappy.parquet
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:459)
        ...
```

The baffling part is that `FileAlreadyExistsException` is caused by Spark's temporary working space.

I am using the local mode of spark and the local filesystem (not HDFS), if this information matters.

What can go wrong here?

Comment: did you try adding a savemode ? overwrite or append

Comment: Yes. I tried both. Problem still exits.  I reckon that write mode works on the actual output, not how the temporary working directory is structured.  In addition, I tried to partitionby on a column that contains only one type of value, then this problem is gone, very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, after several rounds of excruciating trial & error, I find that this issue is caused by **letter case**!

The dataset has city names of different case versions coexisted under the column `City`, like `"APEX"` and `"Apex"` or `"MORRISVILLE"` and `"Morrisville"`.

Inside the spark engine, which is case sensitive, they are treated as different partitions. But probably because the parquet file writer is case insensitive towards the output path (derived out of the value from columns used for partition), what regarded as different partitions are somehow given the same output path, hence the issue.

One exactly same question was asked 6 years ago, yet issue of this level of detail can still hardly be covered by documentation.

[spark: case sensitive partitionBy column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597401/spark-case-sensitive-partitionby-column)

Solution:

```py
out_df = in_df.selectExpr("trim(OBJECTID) AS ID",
                          "trim(NAME) AS NAME",
                          "upper(trim(CITY)) AS CITY", # unify cases
                          "trim(POSTALCODE) AS POSTALCODE",
                          "trim(STATE) AS STATE", "X", "Y")
```